Does IBM MQ 9.3 still support ActiveX applications (AXMQ200.dll)?
I "support" an old webserver application, which uses ServerSide Jscript ActiveX component. This is the IBM MQ WebSphere dll (IBM MQ) called MQAX200.
The latest documentation i can find on ActiveX and MQAX200 is in the 9.1 version (here).
When i search the documentation for 9.2 or 9.3 there is no mention of ActiveX or the MQAX200.dll - does anyone know if the support for this has stopped?
I am still waiting for my organization to get me installation files so i can test it, but was hoping someone here might know.

The MQ ActiveX interface was marked as "deprecated" in MQ 9.0 and actually removed in 9.2. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=920-deprecated-stabilized-removed-features-in-mq
IBM MQ classes for .NET are the recommended replacement technology.
